# Customize mongo docker raise an error when I try to create a new user for database

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am using a mongo docker image. When I trying to create a user and password for a new database I get an error.

It is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

ENV AUTH yes
ENV JOURNALING yes    

ADD run.sh /usr/bin/run.sh
ADD set_mongodb_password.sh /usr/bin/set_mongodb_password.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/run.sh && chmod +x /usr/bin/set_mongodb_password.sh

EXPOSE 27017 28017

CMD ["/usr/bin/run.sh"]
```

Ok, Now my run script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="mongod"
if [ "$AUTH" == "yes" ]; then
    cmd="$cmd --auth"
fi

if [ "$JOURNALING" == "no" ]; then
    cmd="$cmd --nojournal"
fi

$cmd &

if [ ! -f /data/db/.mongodb_password_set ]; then
    set_mongodb_password
fi

fg
```

and my set_mongodb_password script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=${MONGO_USER:-"mongo"}
PASS=${MONGO_PASSWORD:-"mongo"}
DB=${MONGO_DB:-"testdb"}

echo "=> Creating database < ${DB} > with an user < ${USER} > and password  < ${PASS} > in MongoDB"

echo "=> Creating database"
mongo $DB --eval "db.getSiblingDB('${DB}');"

echo "=> Creating user and password"
mongo $DB --eval "db.createUser({user: '${USER}', pwd: '${PASS}', roles:[ { role:'readWrite',db: '${DB}'} ]  } ) ;"
#mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user: 'mongo', pwd: '${PASS}', roles:[{role:'readWrite',db:'$DB'}]});"

echo "=> Done!"
touch /data/db/.mongodb_password_set

echo "========================================================================"
echo "You can now connect to this MongoDB server using:"
echo ""
echo "    mongo ${DB} -u ${USER} -p ${PASS} --host <host> --port <port>"
echo ""
echo "Please remember to change the above password as soon as possible!"
echo "========================================================================"
```

I build and create my mongo image, so when I try to connect with the user and password it return an authentication error. Then I go inside of my mongo container with the `docker exec` command and run the set_mongodb_password script manually, I got the follow error:

```
2015-08-05T06:08:50.550+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on pepedb to execute command { createUser: "pepe", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "pepedb" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 30000.0 } }
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DB.createUser (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101:11)
    at (shell eval):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1101
```

So, I don't know how to solve this error. When I use the simple mongo image and run it. I can go inside the container and run the content of my set_mongodb_password script steps by steps and everything work fine. So I don't understand where is the problem. Maybe I am missing something in the configuration or some mongo parameters. Any help please ?

Comment: do you want that bash script to execute when the container is created or when it is started?

Comment: I want to create the user and password when the container is starting. For that I send the mongo to background with & but it doesn't works. So when I tried to connect to mongo with that user/pass I want to get access.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in run.sh and set_mongodb_password.sh.

In script run.sh you need to add "set -m" right after the line #!bash, because in the last line you use fg. Read the post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196603/can-someone-explain-in-detail-what-set-m-does to understand "set -m" and "fg".

In the same script you need to call set_mongodb_password like /usr/bin/set_mongodb_password.sh instead of set_mongodb_password

The problem of the set_mongodb_password.sh is that it run before run.sh, so you need to add the line below after "#!bash" to wait the mongo goes up:

```
RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of MongoDB service startup"
    sleep 5
    mongo admin --eval "help" >/dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done
```

After doing this you will be able to execute mongo commands and create the user you need.